# Coordinate transformation issue in postgis

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

I have a cad drawing that is suppose to be in FL83-EF that I imported into opengis. However I think that the coordinates were wrong. Is there some sort of transformation that I can run on my data given I know some points on the cad drawing and can use as points of reference.

Comment: "yes", but you'll have to provide more information to get a precise answer. http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Translate.html or http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Affine.html

Answer (score 1):

If the cords were wrong on import then you do not want to use `ST_Transform()`. Simply use [`ST_SetSRID()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html). This will *not* transform them but merely change the internal representation as if you had imported them properly to begin with.

```
UPDATE table
SET geom = ST_SetSRID(geom, srid);
```